# Четкость текста в textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

Приветствую, почему может такое быть?
Пробовал на нескольких ПК, пробовал менять размер текстбокса, пробовал перемещать его по форме.
[image: Генератор ПДФ417 по алкокоду]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="AlcoGenerator.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AlcoGenerator"
    x:Name="icon"
    Height="413.726"
    Width="719"
    RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Grid
        Margin="12,0,13,-92"
        Height="364"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5037,0.4725"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="689">
        <TextBox
            x:Name="tbAlcoIn"
            TextChanged="tbAlcoIn_TextChanged"
            KeyDown="tbAlcoIn_KeyDown"
            Height="25"
            Width="150"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,31,439,0" AutomationProperties.HelpText="Принимается только значение из 19 цифр" />
        <TextBox
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.4974,0.45"
            x:Name="tbAlcoOut_1"
            Height="25"
            Width="550"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="100,0,0,275"
            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <TextBox
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.4974,0.45"
            x:Name="tbAlcoOut_2"
            Height="25"
            Width="550"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="100,0,0,249"
            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <TextBox
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.4974,0.45"
            x:Name="tbAlcoOut_3"
            Height="25"
            Width="550"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="100,0,0,221"
            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <TextBox
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.4974,0.45"
            x:Name="tbAlcoOut_4"
            Height="25"
            Width="550"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="100,0,0,193"
            IsReadOnly="True" />
        <TextBox
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.4974,0.45"
            x:Name="tbAlcoOut_5"
            Height="25"
            Width="550"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="100,0,0,91" >
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-0.171"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>
        <Label
            x:Name="lbAlco"
            Content="Ввод Алкокода"
            FontSize="11"
            Height="26"
            Width="92"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,28,0,0" />
        <Grid Margin="0,67,607,248">
            <Button
                x:Name="btn1"
                Content="Копировать"
                Click="btn1_Click"
                Width="82"
                Height="25"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
            />
            <Button
                Content="Копировать"
                x:Name="btn2"
                Click="btn2_Click"
                Height="25"
                Width="82"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Margin="0,26,0,0" />
        </Grid>
        <Button
            Content="Копировать"
            x:Name="btn3"
            Click="btn3_Click"
            Height="25"
            Width="82"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,121,0,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.655,2.429" />
        <Button
            Content="Копировать"
            x:Name="btn4"
            Click="btn4_Click"
            Height="25"
            Width="82"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Margin="0,149,0,0" />
        <Button
            Content="Копировать"
            x:Name="btn5"
            Click="btn5_Click"
            Width="82"
            Height="25"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="0,0,0,164" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Вопрос об элементе tbAlcoOut_5

Comment: да, давайте ставить диагноз по картинке

Comment: Ну а что показать то, слои, код?

Comment: @IllarionIvanov, да, разметку покажите, желательно убрав всё лишнее, не относящееся к делу

Comment: @Андрей добавил разметку в 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextBox.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform/>
        <SkewTransform/>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-0.171"/>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </TransformGroup>
</TextBox.RenderTransform>
```

Вот он корень зла всем спасибо.
В студии экран меньше получается и проглядел как то...

Comment: в следующий раз разметку пишите сами и проблем не будет

Comment: `RotateTransform Angle="-0.171"` мда, это выглядит странно